# When I am trying extract text from PDF using pdftotext command in Linux , I got an error

Tags: linux, pdf

root@kali:~/Desktop# pdftotext PaySlip.pdf

Syntax Error: Missing 'endstream' or incorrect stream length

What does this mean ? Is it not able to find end of PDF file ?
Please help .

Answer (score 0):

A PDF file contains objects; objects can contain streams (often compressed), and a stream is terminated with `endstream`. Open it in a text editor to get a better idea how it looks lie.

So at least one object in your PDF file may be corrupted, because the given stream length doesn't match the position where `endstream` should be. Other PDF tools may or may not care about this inconsistency (which is why you can do fun things with PDF files).

So: Fix the PDF file, either manually, or you could try tools like `mutool`.